# Object's property is undefined when accessing it through computed props

Tags: vue.js

I'm getting a problem, when I try to access object's proprety through a compted property, it get's undefined. The object is set async.

Two things to be clarified:

1- when I log the object to the console inside the computed function -> property (state) is set. BUT when I log the property itself, it is undefined.

```
  computed: {
    propA() {
      console.log(this.booking);
       // { state: "Draft", product: (...) }
      console.log(this.booking.state);
       //undefined
      console.log(this.booking.product);
       //"Product abc"
  }
}
```

2- `this.booking.state` is correctly bound to the view via `v-model`.

`booking` is set as follows:

```
 props: {
    currentBooking: Object,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      booking: Object,
    };
  },
  async mounted() {
    this.booking = { ...this.currentBooking }; // {product: "Product abc"}
    this.booking.state =  "Draft";
}
```

Comment: How is the `booking` property defined?

Comment: Did you try the vue dev tools? any analysis you can mention?

Comment: I've updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Since the data is set async, the property is `undefined` at the time it's logged.  The only reason you see it when logging the object is thanks to the console's ability to update objects/arrays.  It updates itself to show the *current* value when you click an object to view the properties.

This only works for references (like objects / arrays) because the console uses that reference to update itself.

So when you log the non-object property, you see the data as it was at the time of the log:  `undefined`.  But when you log the object, and then click to expand properties, you see the data as it is now.

Comment: But it logs the object two times and the first time doesn't have any props, since the data are fetched and given to the component through "props".

Comment: Ok, what does that change?  I think you said it's already working so I thought you wanted an explanation of the console

Comment: I mean, the computed function is called after the object is set too, therefore it should have the property "state" defined.

Comment: The computed is called before the `state` property is set, when the child component is first rendered.  Then the async data comes in, the `state` property is set, and the computed is called again.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/re1axqsp - Check the console

Comment: that's exactly what I was expecting by me. But the second log of `state` is also `undefined` in my code.